# Cast bytes to bytes32 using assembly

Tags: solidity, assembly

Is there any way of converting bytes into bytes32 using solidity assembly? (avoiding a loop, and knowing the size of the input bytes array)

Comment: You can look this library for inspiration https://github.com/pouladzade/Seriality